# trouble while installing KWin window manager

Tags: 12.04, kde, window-manager

I installed the Kde windows manager in ubuntu 12.04 using the command:
sudo apt-get install kde-window-manager

the installation was succesful.

I then logged out and in the login screen only ubuntu, ubuntu 2d and awesome(which i had installed earlier) options are available.

How do i start KWin??

Do i need to restart for the effects to to take place?

Edit 1:

i restarted my system and still no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem, and found that i was missing /usr/bin/startkde.

Fixed it with: sudo apt-get install kde-workspace-bin